# Error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

This code have error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression", I think it because the strDate and data from my query QryStockRinci.

Public Function ReturnAmountSaleRev(strDate As Date, strProductID As String, curAmount As Currency, curAmountSale As Currency) As Variant

`Dim curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO As Integer
Dim varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO As Variant


'Get the total Amount for the current ProductID up to and including given PO.
curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO = DSum("Stock", "QryStockRinci", "[Tanggal] <= '" & strDate & "' AND [kode_barcode] = '" & strProductID & "'")

'If there is enough in SalesAmount to cover the whole cost, return the whole Amount.
If curAmountSale - curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO >= 0 Then
    ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(curAmount, "0.00")
Else
    'Get the the total Amount in ProductID prior to current PO.
    varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO = DSum("Stock", "QryStockRinci", "[Tanggal] < '" & strDate & "' AND [kode_barcode] = '" & strProductID & "'")

    'If current PO is first in ProductID, varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO will be null;
    'determine covered amount.
    If IsNull(varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO) = True Then
        If curAmount <= curAmountSale Then
            ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(curAmount, "0.00")
        Else
            ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(curAmountSale, "0.00")
        End If
    Else
        'If current PO is not first in ProductID, varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO
        'will have a value; determine the covered amount.
        varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO = curAmountSale - varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO

        If varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO <= 0 Then
            ReturnAmountSaleRev = 0
        Else
            ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO, "0.00")
        End If
    End If
End If`

End Function

Comment: Could you let us know which line is the error on?

Comment: curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO = DSum("Stock", "QryStockRinci", "[Tanggal] <= '" & strDate & "' AND [kode_barcode] = '" & strProductID & "'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to treat Dates as Dates and not strings, also try to enclose Domain functions with Nz to avoid assigning Null values to Integer or any other Data Type that is other than Variant.

```
Public Function ReturnAmountSaleRev(strDate As Date, strProductID As String, curAmount As Currency, curAmountSale As Currency) As Variant
    Dim curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO As Long
    Dim varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO As Variant

    'Get the total Amount for the current ProductID up to and including given PO.'
    curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO = Nz(DSum("Stock", "QryStockRinci", "[Tanggal] <= " & Format(strDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " AND [kode_barcode] = '" & strProductID & "'"), 0)

    'If there is enough in SalesAmount to cover the whole cost, return the whole Amount.'
    If curAmountSale - curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO >= 0 Then
        ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(curAmount, "0.00")
    Else
        'Get the the total Amount in ProductID prior to current PO.'
        varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO = Nz(DSum("Stock", "QryStockRinci", "[Tanggal] < " & Format(strDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & "' AND [kode_barcode] = '" & strProductID & "'"), 0)

        'If current PO is first in ProductID, varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO will be null;'
        'determine covered amount.'
        If IsNull(varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO) = True Then
            If curAmount <= curAmountSale Then
                ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(curAmount, "0.00")
            Else
                ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(curAmountSale, "0.00")
            End If
        Else
            'If current PO is not first in ProductID, varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO
            'will have a value; determine the covered amount.'
            varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO = curAmountSale - varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO

            If varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO <= 0 Then
                ReturnAmountSaleRev = 0
            Else
                ReturnAmountSaleRev = Format(varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO, "0.00")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, but it returns Overflow error pointing to the same statement

Comment: Your value must be a number greater than the one an Integer could handle, Try declaring them as Long. Also please always refer to the Line of Code that is throwing the error. It is very hard to identify otherwise.

Comment: Paul, I have a little problem for this function. It return wrong value  if there is data with same date for same product. Maybe I need to add a field row_number to differentiate the data. can you help me ?

Comment: Sure, it could be helpful if you provided some sample data.

Comment: I already solved that problem with added auto number field for that table and insert data to that table sorting in order that i want

Comment: Glad you have it sorted. Good luck ! :)